# how update woocommerce product meta_data with postman

Tags: woocommerce, postman, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

how update woocommerce product meta_data with postman

please help update

```json
{
    "id": 15841,
    "name": "LCD IPHONE 8G WHITE ORG CHIN",
    "slug": "lcd-iphone-8g-white-org-chin",
    "status": "publish",
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "id": 452463,
            "key": "_erp_code",
            "value": "bBALOw92agF4QB4O"
        },
        {
            "id": 464050,
            "key": "_wp_old_date",
            "value": "2022-05-12"
        },
        {
            "id": 464051,
            "key": "_holo_sku",
            "value": "0118657"
        },
        {
            "id": 464052,
            "key": "_ipeir_woo_products_tabs",
            "value": []
        }
    ]
}
```

only update **_holo_sku** value

pust method in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well documented in the WooCommerce REST API docs. Search in `Products` > `Update a product` section ([click here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product)).

You need a **PUT** request to the `products` endpoint URL *(replace your product ID)*:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/<id>
```

Your `$data` should only contain the `meta_data` (only `key` and `value`, since `id` is redundant):

```
"meta_data": [
    {
        "key": "_holo_sku",
        "value": "0118657"
    },
]
```

WC REST API is fully integrated in Postman natively, so this should be pretty easy and straightforward.